# Use an xlsx file uploaded by the client (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My goal is from an xlsx file that loads the client, represent the variables using Leaflet.

When I give the absolute path of the example that I have on my server everything is fine, the problem comes when I try to give the file from `<input type = "file">`.

From what I have been able to read in other questions, a "fakepath" is created for security reasons, but this means that I can not access the file that the client leaves in the input.

I'm new to programming and I'm pretty lost in terms of security and this stuff. If someone had a solution, I would be very grateful.

HTML

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

JS

```
/* DATA --- Read xlsx file (foreign code - PLUGIN xlsx.full.min.js ) */
function readXlsxFile(url, sheet, cb) {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("GET", url, true);
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  oReq.onerror = function() {
    cb(new Error("Could not load file " + url));
  }
  oReq.onload = function() {
    var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
    // Convertir datos a binario
    var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
    var arr = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    var bstr = arr.join("");

    var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
    var sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[sheet];
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
    var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: true });
    cb(null, result);
  }
  oReq.send();
};


function readXlsxFileSheet(url, cb) {
  const rateFile = serializeMapFormValues().rate
  if (rateFile === "travelers" || rateFile === "travelersPoblation" || rateFile === "travelersForeignPercent" || rateFile === "travelersNatPercent") {
    readXlsxFile(url, 0, cb);
  } else if (rateFile === "ruralTravelers" || rateFile === "ruralForeignPercent" || rateFile === "ruralPercent" || rateFile === "ruralNatPercent") {
    readXlsxFile(url, 1, cb);
  } else if (rateFile === "apartTravelers" || rateFile === "apartPoblation" || rateFile === "apartForeignPercent" || rateFile === "apartNatPercent") {
    readXlsxFile(url, 2, cb);
  } else if (rateFile === "hotelTravelers" || rateFile === "hotelForeignPercent" || rateFile === "hotelNatPercent") {
    readXlsxFile(url, 3, cb);
  } else {
    console.log("Lost variable for sheet");
  }
};
const submitButton = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  //Catch path and variable from the HTML form
  let fileUrl = serializeMapFormValues().url;
  let fileRow = serializeMapFormValues().rate;

  // Update map data
  readXlsxFileSheet(fileUrl, function(error, data) {
    // code
  });
});
```

If I change fileUrl `("C:\fakepath\turismo_ejemplo_resuelto.xlsx")` for `"files/turismo_ejemplo_resuelto.xlsx"` everything is fine.

Comment: Where is `readXlsxFileSheet()` defined?

Comment: I just added the readXlsxFileSheet and readXlsxFile functions, I hope it helps.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation at tutorials at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications - dealing with local files is very different from files that the user provides via forms.